# Vue JS: add values from API JSon

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm new developer in Vue JS.
below is my response body, and i wanted to sum `amount` values that has `is_paid:true` with `paid_amount` only.. is there a way to do this in Vue JS?

EDit: for ex sum 30 (`amount`) + 20 (`paid_amount`) with out 100 since it has `is_paid:false`

```html
{
    "payment" : {
        "installment_payment" : {
            "installments" : [
                          amount:30,
                                date: "",
                                is_paid: true,
                            },
                            {
                                amount: 100,
                                date: "",
                                is_paid: false,

                            },
                            {
                                amount: "",
                                date: "",
                                is_paid: false,
                            },
                              {
                                amount: "",
                                date: "",
                                is_paid: true,
                            }
                        ],

                        remaining: ""

                    },
                    paid_amount: 20,
                },

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter for paid installments....

```
let installments = apiResponse.payment.installment_payment.installments;
let paidInstallments = installments.filter(obj => obj.is_paid);
```

Sum using reduce...

```
let totalPaid = paidInstallments.reduce((sum, obj) => sum + parseInt(obj.amount), 0);
```

Demo...

```js
let installments = [
  { amount:5, is_paid:true }, { amount:10, is_paid:false },
  { amount:15, is_paid:true }, { amount:20, is_paid:false }
];

// 5 and 15 are paid, so sum should be 20
let paidInstallments = installments.filter(obj => obj.is_paid);
let totalPaid = paidInstallments.reduce((sum, obj) => sum + parseInt(obj.amount), 0);
console.log(totalPaid);
```

You could also filter and reduce in one go, like this...

```
// filter all installments and assign 0 as the payment when is_paid is false
let totalPaid = installments.reduce((sum, obj) => {
  const amountPaid = obj.is_paid ? parseInt(obj.amount) : 0;
  return sum + amountPaid;
}, 0);
console.log(totalPaid);
```